# How do I initialize an int with a hexadecimal value?

Tags: c#, game-development, sharpdevelop

i want to input 
public int a=004DF73C;

but it is showing an error of ';' expected (CS1002)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `0x` at the front to signify it is a hex format.

`public int a = 0x4DF73C;`

Comment: thank you so much, ive been trying to run it for a month now. now my program running great

Comment: @CoffeeStain Note that those "characters" are called hexadecimal.